# AJAX issue with WooCommerce add to basket

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have nearly completed a site using WooCommerce now and everything appears to be working as I want, except for one thing.

I have some products on the homepage that use the same code as each product in the shop. When you click add to basket the AJAX does trigger and add them to the basket but, the animation so you know something is happening is missing.

When you go into the shop and add a product to the basket the animation works and afterwards there is a tick so you know the product was added successfully - This does not happen on the homepage.

I have double checked that my products on the homepage do have the class "product_type_simple" if its a simple product (there are variations as well which I know it should not work on) and that they have the data attribute "data_product_id". Thats all fine.

I'm sure I've missed something really very obvious but I can't see why the animation is not working and there are no errors in console log to suggest there is a problem with the AJAX.

The site is: http://telford-webdesign.co.uk/ I hope someone can point out what I have missed!

Thanks in advance :)

Kirsty

Comment: Hi Kirsty, it could be that you're making an AJAX request followed shortly by a GET to another page.. when the browser starts fetching the next page javascript etc ceases to run until the new page is loaded. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for responding. Some of the products have variations in which case I don't expect the animation to work on those because you need to go to the full product to select your option.

There are some "simple" products on the homepage that should have animation over the button but don't.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix this thanks to a clever person from Twitter.

All I needed to do was add the class ".woocommerce" to my homepage template. I added it to my main container class and that fixed it. :)